# how can I use twitter bootstrap table formatting with playframework crud module?

Tags: playframework, twitter-bootstrap

Twitter bootstrap uses `<table class="table">` for table formatting.

Playframework CRUD uses `<table>` for formatting CRUD tables.

In my CRUD\list.html file I see only:

```
<div id="crudListTable">
    #{crud.table /}
</div>
```

without a way to add attributes to the table tag.

How would one apply this `class="table"` attribute to CRUD tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have peeked into the code of the crud.table tag, and the  element is rendered without any logic for controlling the class. So, the crud.table simply does not support this.

As I see it, you have 2 options.

1) Append class with javascript

```
    <div id="crudParent">
        #{crud.table /}
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#crudParent>.table').addClass('table');
    </script>
```

2) create your own crud.table tag. Copy/paste the original tag, and set the class of the table within the tag.